# Can't execute "git rev-parse --git-dir" on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

As the Title says, my Jenkins Pipeline hangs on the following Code

```
def exitcode
try {
    exitcode = sh(returnStatus: true, script: '[ -d .git ] || git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1')
} catch (error) {
    echo error
}
```

The Console Output of Jenkins is

```
[tmpTest] Running shell script
+ [ -d .git ]
+ git rev-parse --git-dir
(processing circle)
```

The Job hangs at this Step till I press Abort, which will then give me the Error that the Script returned Exitcode 128 (which is expected)

I didn't found anything about that which helps me solving this, so I would appropriate if someone could help me.

Comment: `--git-dir` needs a value which is a path to a git directory as `--git-dir=<path>`.

Comment: @ElpieKay that's wrong. If no Path is given, the current Directory is used.
Maybe I should mention that the Command works as expected when used in the Terminal

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I thought it was the `--git-dir` in `git --git-dir=<path> <command>`.

Comment: Any chance that removing `> /dev/null 2>&1` let you see error message?

Comment: @Arount Not sure if I tried it already but I will check that tomorrow, my work for today is done :)

Comment: @Arount after some testing, I run into the Same Error on different Commands. It seems that the sh command does not work in my Pipeline...
I'm using the SCM scripted Pipeline and sh-commands that are executed with steps.sh are not working at all